# How to use jQueryUI (variable) with MySQL query

Tags: c#, jquery, mysql, asp.net, jquery-ui-datepicker

I've placed a jQueryUICalendar control on my WebForm wherein I'd like to have users of said form be able to pick a (start) date and (end) date.   I need those (date) values that the user selects to be passed (as variables) to MySQL for a Query that needs to run once the user pushes a button on the form.   My code is below:

--jQuery code--

```
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" >
        $(function(){
             $("startDate").datepicker({ dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd' });
             $("endDate").datepicker({ dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'   }).bind("change",function(){

    var minValue = $(this).val();
    minValue = $.datepicker.parseDate("yy-mm-dd", minValue);
    minValue.setDate(minValue.getDate()+1);
    $("#to").datepicker( "option", "minDate", minValue );

    var startDate = $(this).datepicker( "jQueryUICalendar1.Text");
    var endDate = $(this).datepicker( "jQueryUICalendar2.Text");

       })

    });
</script>
```

Now here's the MySQL c0de I've been using:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>" ProviderName="<%$ ConnectioNStrings:ConnectionString.ProviderName %>" SelectCommand="SELECT stamp as 'Date', order_No as 'Order #', places.label as 'Location' FROM order_info, places WHERE originating_places_id = '123' and places.label = 'Detroit, MI' and stamp between '20150101' and now();">

<SelectParameters>
<asp:QueryStringParameter Name="sDate" QueryStringField="order_stamp" DbType="Date" />
<asp:QueryStringParameter Name="eDate" QueryStringField="order_stamp" DbType="Date" />
</SelectParameters>
```

^ and as long as I inline code the query everything works as expected.  The moment I attempt to do something like the following:

**e.g.**,  stamp between `@sDate` and `@eDate`

the query fails.   Furthermore, it seems like SQL doesn't even acknowledge the datepicker at all.    I'm -SURE- it's b/c I'm going all noob-style about this, but ---- if one of you C# / jQueryUI / MySQL gurus out there could tell me what I'm doing wrong it'd be greatly appreciated.

Comment: p.s.,  I'm new to Stack;;   my apologies for the formatting-related issues in this post.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
protected void btnUpdateData_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    String startDate = jQueryUICalendar1.text; 
    String endDate = jQueryUICalendar2.text;
    DataSet ds = getData(startDate, endDate);
    if(ds != null and ds.tables.count > 0){
        bindGrid(ds.Tables[0]);
    }
}

Private DataSet getData(string sDate, string eDate){
    DataSet ds = default(DataSet);
    SqlConnection cnx = new SqlConnection("ConnectionString");
    String query = "SELECT stamp as 'Date', order_No as 'Order #', places.label as 'Location' FROM order_info, places WHERE originating_places_id = '123' and places.label = 'Detroit, MI' and stamp between '@sDate' and '@eDate'";
   SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, cnx);
   cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sDate", sDate);
   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@eDate", eDate);
   sqlDataAdapter da = New SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
   try{
        cnx.Open();
        da.Fill(ds);
        cnx.Close();            }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Debug.Print(ex.Message);
    }
    finally
    {
        if (cnx != null) cnx.Close();
    }

    return ds;
}

private void bindGrid(DataTable dt){
    gridView.DataSource = dt;
    gridView.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: a bit of confusion over here. :)    Hope you can help with an explanation.

-->  
String myString = DataAccess.getDataMethod1('parameter string');

List<string> myList = DataAccess.getDataMethod2('parameter string 1', 'parameter string 2');

^ I'm still pretty new to the language (C#) ---  but wouldn't that method (to call the database) be all that is required to render to GridView?  Why would you need to implement that last snippet you posted? (I hope this isn't a dumb question --- just trying to learn)

Comment: Do you have a gridview? your question never mentioned a gridview. The last code snippet is just showing how to call static methods from a Data Access class in your codebehind.  And load that data to variables that can then be used for any purpose. You could populate a gridview or a repeater. Or output the data in any way you choose. Honestly, I'm still confused as to what your actual question was. I may have misunderstood what you were really trying to do but I looked like you were having trouble figuring out how to pass parameters to your database query.

Comment: ^ my apologies for the confusion, @GreggDuncan .   This is what I have:

I've created a WebForm (*.aspx) that has 2 text boxes (jQueryUICalendar1 & jQueryCalendar2), 2 buttons (e.g.,  Update Results,  Export to Excel), and a GridView to display the MySQL results returned by the values depicted in jQueryUICalendar.

My QUESTION (primarily) was how to pass the selected calendar (jQuery) value to c#, so that it can be passed and used in MySQL, which you basically already answered for me in your last post ---- now I'm jjust trying to figure out how to implement it :)

Comment: I edited my answer now that I have a better understanding of what you're trying to do. In the Update Results button click event handler you want to get the values from your jquery ui calendar textboxes. pass those to your getData method which will give you back a dataset of your data. make sure your DataSet contains at least 1 table. Then pass that table to a bind grid method which simply binds the DataTable to the grid view. As long as your DataField matches the column names in the DataTable it should display properly .